# Cannot start Java class

Tags: java, classloader, command-prompt, .class-file

I seem to be following instructions in [the book I'm using](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Java-Programming-24-Hour-Trainer.productCd-0470889640.html) as well as in [Oracle's Java SE docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#start) but cannot overcome the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.practicalJava.lesson25.StartServer
```

I'm using the following command line on my Windows 7 box:

```
[C:\>]java -classpath /Practical_Java/Lesson25/bin -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Practical_Java/Lesson25/bin/ com.practicalJava.lesson25.StartServer
```

From the docs:

```
    start java -classpath classDir -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:classDir/ example.hello.Server

where classDir is the root directory of the class file tree
```

My compiled by Eclipse classes are in package `com.practicalJava.lesson25`.

My **bin** directory is located at

```
C:\Practical_Java\Lesson25\
```

My **StartServer.class** file is located at:

```
C:\Practical_Java\Lesson25\bin\com\practicalJava\lesson25
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong. But what???

*** UPDATE: ***

Typo: Start`Sever` instead of Start`Server`

Comment: I would use an IDE, it is faster to develop and debug in and it will setup your class path correctly.

Comment: I'm using `Eclipse`, but I need to launch all the three `RMI` components (registry, server, and client) in different JVMs.

Comment: You can run three different JVMs from eclipse.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with RMI or the codebase feature. It is just a misuse of the command line. There is no such thing as  'bin' directory for Java programs. Your .class file is simply in the wrong place in the file system.

Comment: @EJP - 
It's exactly where Eclipse put it. For Eclipse project structure (not Java in general) `bin` plays its role.

Comment: Then Eclipse has put it in the wrong place. It should be in a directory hierarchy corresponding to the package hierarchy. The *head* of that hierarchy is the CLASSPATH.

Comment: get sure you start the console with admin rights.

Comment: Yes, I have admin rights and I included package information into my post.

Comment: @EJP - Yes, you're right this is some kind `CLASSPATH` issue.  I'm still at loss where I made a typo or other stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Write Command for start the Server :

> rmic HelloServer
>
> start rmiregistry

Write Command for start the Client :

> java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.16\webapps\ROOT\RMI\RMI" -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/RMI/ -Djava.security.policy=Client.policy HelloClient

=================================

If you are using manaully deploy in the Tomcat folder then you should set the environment variable of classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.16\webapps\ROOT\RMI\RMI"
Upto RMI folder where you put the code....

This is really working....

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. Unfortunately it does not seem to have anything to do with my question.